# mlextend plot_decision_regions with model fit on Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-visualization, mlxtend

I'm a big fan of mlxtend's `plot_decision_regions` function, (http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/#examples , https://stackoverflow.com/a/43298736/1870832)

It accepts an `X`(just two columns at a time), `y`, and (fitted) classifier `clf` object, and then provides a pretty awesome visualization of the relationship between model predictions, true y-values, and a pair of independent variables.

A couple restrictions:
`X` and `y` have to be numpy arrays, and `clf` needs to have a `predict()` method. Fair enough. My problem is that in my case, the classifier `clf` object I would like to visualize has already been fitted on a Pandas DataFrame...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Create arbitrary dataset for example
df = pd.DataFrame({'Planned_End': np.random.uniform(low=-5, high=5, size=50),
                   'Actual_End':  np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=50),
                   'Late':        np.random.random_integers(low=0,  high=2, size=50)}
)

# Fit a Classifier to the data
# This classifier is fit on the data as a Pandas DataFrame
X = df[['Planned_End', 'Actual_End']]
y = df['Late']

clf = xgb.XGBClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

So now when I try to use `plot_decision_regions` passing X/y as numpy arrays...

```
# Plot Decision Region using mlxtend's awesome plotting function
plot_decision_regions(X=X.values,
                      y=y.values,
                      clf=clf,
                      legend=2)
```

I (understandably) get an error that the model can't find the column names of the dataset it was trained on

```
ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['Planned_End', 'Actual_End'] ['f0', 'f1']
expected Planned_End, Actual_End in input data
training data did not have the following fields: f1, f0
```

In my actual case, it would be a big deal to avoid training our model on Pandas DataFrames. Is there a way to still produce `decision_regions` plots for a classifier trained on a Pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
X = df[['Planned_End', 'Actual_End']].values
y = df['Late'].values
```

and proceed to:

```
clf = xgb.XGBClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)

plot_decision_regions(X=X,
                      y=y,
                      clf=clf,
                      legend=2)
```

OR `fit & plot` using `X.values` and `y.values`

Comment: thanks for the response Sangeetha. However, this solution doesn't work for me because you are explicitly training the model on numpy arrays, not a Pandas Dataframe, in order to get `plot_decision_regions` to work.

My question concluded "In my actual case, it would be a big deal to avoid training our model on Pandas DataFrames. Is there a way to still produce decision_regions plots for a classifier trained on a Pandas DataFrame?"

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338972/valueerror-feature-names-mismatch-in-xgboost-in-the-predict-function . The only way it works is while converting the pandas dataframe to numpy array. I tried the above solution as well fitting the classfier with X.values, y.values & then plotting decision regions. This isnt an issue with mlxtend.plotting, but with xgboostclassifier.